# Нужны ли в предложении запятые? Если да, то почему

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, однородные-неоднородные-определения, пояснительные

*Я написал последнюю дипломную работу.*

Comment: Дарья, всё-таки хотелось бы узнать, какой смысл заложен в это предложение. На будущее: приводите, пожалуйста, контекст, а также поясняйте, в каком месте имеются сомнения в постановке знаков препинания. А если ответ понятен и решил вопрос, отметьте его галочкой как принятый. В дальнейшем (когда наберёте 15 баллов) Вы сможете отмечать все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх.

Answer (score 3):

Пунктуация будет зависеть от смысла.

1. *Я написал **последнюю дипломную** работу.*

В этом случае определения неоднородны, запятая между ними не ставится, пауза отсутствует.
Смысл такой: была написана первая дипломная работа, затем следующая, пятая, десятая, и вот пришёл черёд последней (больше не буду, не хочу писать дипломные работы или просто на данном этапе это пока последняя).

2. *Я написал последнюю, **дипломную,** работу.*

Второе определение является пояснением первого: *последнюю, а именно (то есть) дипломную, работу.*
Смысл: учился, учился, написал одну работу, например реферат, другую, например курсовую, ещё и ещё, а теперь, наконец, последнюю, дипломную.

> Слова, поясняющие смысл предшествующего члена предложения, **выделяются** (или отделяются) **знаками препинания** (запятыми, тире, двоеточием).
> [[Пояснительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119)]

На мой взгляд, тире лучше подчёркивает необходимую информацию и способствует её интонационному выделению:
*Я написал последнюю – **дипломную** – работу.*

3. *Я написал **последнюю, дипломную** работу.*

Вариант с одной запятой, думаю, не очень удачен: определения не подходят для простого перечисления в качестве однородных членов.